# Problem with parked domain for my mutisite

Tags: multisite

I have a website with “.com” but recently I bought another domain wth “.ir” and I pointed this one to my main website. However, when I type mywebsite.ir in browser, instead of being directed to my main page, I am directed to a /wp-signup.php page with my new domain name added as new user!

I use wp multisite.

Is there anyway I can fix this problem?

[mywebsite](https://rastmard.com)
[myparkeddomain](http://rastmard.ir)

Answer (score 2):

Merely pointing a domain at your site isn't enough to make things work. What's happening here:

- You have WordPress configured on the `.com`
- Traffic from the `.ir` domain is pointing at the same server
- WordPress doesn't realize they're the same thing and instead assumes you're trying to set up a *new* blog on a multisite installation

You'll need to tell the server how to handle the `.ir` requests. If you want these domains to serve the *same* site, you'll likely need to set one to *redirect* to the other. Meaning anyone who visits the `.com` is redirected to the `.ir` (or vice-versa, depending on your preference).

WordPress Multi-site will otherwise treat these as *separate* sites within your installation.

### Another Alternative

If you need both domains to be treated as separate sites, but still serve the same content, take a look at a domain "alias" plugin like [Mercator](https://github.com/humanmade/Mercator).

Comment: Can he use a domain mapping plugin for multisite maybe?

Comment: Yes, that's why I suggested a domain alias plugin (identical thing, just different term, and Mercator seems to be the most recently updated one I could find).